# Do T4 trader offers change?

Tags: fallout-4

I have two Tier 4 traders in my settlement and i want to know if their offers will change?
Someone on reddit mentions that they have legendary weapons that refresh daily.
([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3tjcxf/what_do_the_tier_4_settlement_vendors_sell/cx6xtlt))

I know that it doesn't change daily (basic items refresh, likly on a 72h base), but do they offer new legendary items.
Like new type of legendary weapons or armor, after I bought what they had?

Comment: I had some lesser merchants in my settlement, and their inventory refreshed daily. They didn't have any legendary items, so I can't say for sure, but maybe.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the fact that all legendary items from Traders are unique named items and there are a fixed number of these it doesn't seem like this rumor contains any value!

Also I have played a lot more since I asked this question and so far there have been no new legendary items to buy, neither at the traders at my settlements or at any others.

In my experience it seems as if **the initial legendary items are the only ones that will ever be available to buy at traders**.

It would be nice if people can confirm if this is also their experience in the comments.